# Four-model-relationship select and aggregate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need some guidance for how to solve this issue, please point me in the right direction.

I’ve got four models setup:

```
1.  Area (has many subareas)
2.  Subarea (has many buildings and has many persons through buildings)
3.  Building (has many persons)
4.  Person (contains a field named age)
```

Through the subarea model I am able to retrieve the average age for each building within that subarea, because of the “has many through” relationship between subarea and person:

```
$mySubareaModel::with(‘avg_age_per_building’)->get()

Subarea:
Name: xxx
Lat: yyy
Long: zzz
Building_avg_age: (a list of buildings and the avg age) 
      Building 1:
          AvgAge: 30
      Building 2:
          AvgAge: 25
      Building 3:
          AvgAge: 21
```

So far so good, but now I would like to do the same for the area level where there is no direct relationship to person.
For each area I want a list of subareas and their average ages, like below:

```
Area:
Name: xxx
Subareas: (a list of subareas and the avg age) 
      Subarea 1:
          AvgAge: 23
      Subarea 2:
          AvgAge: 21
```

What are my options here?

1. Do I need to do a complete chain of joins within the area model (selectRaw, join, group) to get what I want?
2. Could I somehow make use of the already working code that produces the list on subarea level?

   $myAreaModel::with(‘subarea. avg_age_per_building’)->some_kind_of_joins_and aggregation_here

If so, how would the join and aggregation look like?

3. Other options? Would a "**has many buildings through subarea**" in the area model make things easier?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your relations, does nesting the related models not work?

[Have a look at nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
Area::with('subarea.building.person')->get();
```

Update:

Maybe performing operations on the collection like this may be what you're looking for. I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but it may guide you

```
$result = Area::with('subarea.building.person')->get();

    return $result->subarea->map(function($subareas, $key){
        return $subareas->building->map(function($buildings, $key){
            return $buildings->reduce(function($carry, $building){
                return $carry + $building->avg('age');
            })/ count($buildings) *100;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hm I think it works. But Im not sure how to do the rest in order to acheive my target. Your code would give me access to all lists But i need to process the data to produce the example in my post...group and aggregate It on area and subarea level

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out when i get back home